# CSS working for mobile view but not wide screens

Tags: html, css

My CSS is working for mobile view but not wide screens. Limiting the height to a certain number of pixels for the container of the image is working on small screens but not on wide screens.

```css
.spandemo {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 39%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .spandemo {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 30%;
  }
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .column img {
    max-height: 140px;
    height: 70%;
    width: auto;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  img {
    max-height: 100px !important;
    height: 70%;
    width: auto;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column"><img class="responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/left/200/300" style="width:50%" border="1" />
    <img class="responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/right/200/300" style="float:right; width:50%" border="1" />
    <span style="float:left;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Before</span><span class="spandemo" style="float:left;">&nbsp;&nbsp;After</span></div>
</div>
```

It (limiting the height to a certain number of pixels for the container of the image) is working on small screens but not on wide screens

Comment: Hi ! I made your code a runnable snippet (with the `<>` button) and with example images from [Lorem Picsum](https://picsum.photos/). Your media queries were missing the closing `}` but I assume for just forgot to copy&paste those?

Comment: Protips: Don't use inline styles, especially when you already have a stylesheet. It mucks up your markup and makes it harder to interpret your document. Don't use whitespace characters for spacing. Use margin, padding, flexbox properties, etc.

Comment: Please revise your post to be more clear about your goal. Instead of repeating yourself to meet post requirements you should've added more detail. "Isn't working" isn't a problem statement. Be very specific about what you expect to happen.

Comment: @PeterKrebs That missing closing brace seems to have been the actual issue. When making changes like that, please test the result to see if the behavior matches what is described.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to increase the max-height of the image in min-width: 600px, like

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  img {
    max-height: 380px !important;
    height: 70%;
    width: auto;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sameera, it didn't help! @Peter Krebs, I added the missing, closing flower bracket but it still doesn't change on wide screens (only the media command for mobile view is used for all widths, including for wide screens).

Comment: I was able to make it work with this:    
````     
.column { width: 98%; float: right; } } .column img { max-height: 129px; height: 100%; width: auto; } } @media screen and (max-width: 600px) { .column { width: 90%; float: right; } } @media screen and (max-width: 600px) { .column img { max-height: 129px; height: 70%; width: 90%; padding-right: 10px; } } @media screen and (min-width: 600px) { .column img { max-height: 372px; height: 70%; width: 90%; padding-right: 10px; } } </style> 
````      
However, I request @Peter Krebs or someone else to help reduce the @media CSS codes.